# BB10 - Able to focus in text box but not able to type

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-webworks

I have this BB10 app that will check for empty value fields, then alert the user regarding the empty field and once the user has click on 'OK' focus will be place in the text box. I can place focus in the text box but I could not type anything in it.

The text field and button

```
 strDetailClaim += '<div class="detailsRow">';
 strDetailClaim += '<div class="detailsLabel">GL CODE</div><div 
 class="detailsValue"><input type="text" id="glCode_'+i+'"  
 name="glCode_'+referenceNo+'" size="9" value="'+detailsGLCode+'"></div>';

 strDetailClaim += '<span class="spanApprove"><button id="approveButton"   
 class="formButton" type="button" ontouchstart="shadowHighlight(this)" 
 ontouchend="noShadowHighlight(this); setTimeout(function()
 {approveClaim(\''+referenceNo+'\')},300)">APPROVE</div>';
```

Part of approveClaim function

```
 alert("GL Code for claim number " + indieClaim[referenceNo].details[i].runno + " must  
 not be empty. Please key-in GL Code");
 setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('glCode_'+i+'').focus()},200);
 return false;
```

The strange thing is that if I remove the alert function I can get focus in textbox and is able to type something in it.

Am I missing something here? Is there anyway to allow alert then allow user to type in the text box?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the alert after setting focus?

Also try setting document.activeElement to document.getElementById('glCode_'+i) ?

Comment: I have tried placing alert after focus but still user can't type in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the case for you, but I had this exact same problem.

My issue was that for some crazy reason I had this in my CSS

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
```

...which allowed me to click on the text input, but it would not allow me to type.

Comment: I checked the css, there isn't -webkit-user-select: none; in it.